# find top value dynamically from drop down menu using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm using Python with Selenium. I'm trying to automate an application in which i need to extract top value from a drop menu. The values keep on changing so i cannot pass a static xpath to my selenium python code.

I tried the following code but none of them working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI
select=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='code' and @name='Code1']")
for option in select.options:
    print(option.text,option.get_attribute('value'))
```

The idea is to find all the values and extract the top value. When i print `select.options` I don't see anything.
I extracted the following HTML by inspecting the drop down menu.

```
<select name="Code1" style="width:250px" class="code" id="code">
    <option value="Select Code">Select  Code</option>
    <option value="GGGSGSG:C">GGGSGSG:C</option>
    <option value="AHR060">AHR060--NORTH</option>
    <option value="AGSGGS">AGSGGS--PTSTTS</option>
    <option value="NANNAN">NANNAN--BTSTT</option>
</select>
```

Now the values keep changing so I cannot pass any specific value in xpath. I need to find all option values dynamically and pass the top one to a variable and using that variable call xpath and click the element.

Comment: What is your exact business requirement? `find all the values and extract the top value` - what does **top value** means? How do you differentiate between `find` and `extract`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to select the top element using index.

```
select = UI.Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='code' and 
@name='Code1']"))
select.select_by_index(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select as WebDriverSelect
select_element = WebDriverSelect(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='code' and @name='Code1']"))
select_element.select_by_index(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `css` selector for the first value, something like:

```
select#code option + option
```

or xpath

```
//select[@id='code']/option[2]
```